# How to show company name or logo in url

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to show my company name in url

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNMVP.png)

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked before. You can fin the answer here http://superuser.com/questions/565422/why-do-some-websites-show-the-company-name-next-to-the-url.

Answer (score 5):

It's not company name and logo. It's to show that the information is encrypted using a certificate.

[image]

It is a security feature put in place to verify that the website is actually served by the company it claims to be from.

See [this](https://superuser.com/a/565426/470882) answer that explains it well.

To implement SSL, you need:

1. An SSL certificate from a reliable SSL certificate provider like
   Comodo, Symanted, Godaddy, DigiCert etc...
2. A hosting that supports the use of SSL.

[Youtube - SSL Certificate Explained](https://youtu.be/SJJmoDZ3il8)

Comment: Your answer is just a blunt copy of this previously answered question (which is likely the first google result you'll get): http://superuser.com/questions/565422/why-do-some-websites-show-the-company-name-next-to-the-url. Just give the reference to a questions if it has been asked and answered before instead of just copying it like it is your own answer.

Comment: I just gave a quick info in my answer and gave a link to original answer. You can see the link in the text **See this answer that explains it well.**

Comment: Except if you can give some additional meaningful information to the question you reference, just giving the url is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your information.Actually I don't know . now i have got information for you . Now i need more information (how to achieve ).Any link or information con you send

Comment: @MahfuzMorshed I remember long ago when I needed an insight as to what SSL is, I came across this video. Please visit it once [SSL Certificate Explained](https://youtu.be/SJJmoDZ3il8)

Answer (score 0):

To get this, you have to get a special SSL certificate called an [Extended Validation](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-extended-validation-certificate/) This requires a "through vetting of your organization", and by my research, [cost upwards of $600](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl/ev-ssl/). People get these to ensure their customers that they are using the right platform, and that they are not subject to man-in-middle or other phishing attacks, they are specifically designed to be hard to get.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you actually mean the icon that will show up beside the title, NOT the HTTPS indicator icon: put an image file in the root context called favicon.ico